# How to maintain height and width between two different HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I want to maintain the height of my `img` element with the `input` element using CSS and html only. Any guidance will be appreciated I am very new to these things. 
Here are some parts of the code

```
<!-- Main section of the html part--> 
<main>
 <!-- Division with Search Bar as an input element and the svg as an image--> 
            <div class="searchDiv">
                <!-- A label --> 

                  <label class="searchBar" id="search">Taste of home right at your finger tips <br>   </label>
                 <!-- Search Bar --> 
                  <input type="text" id="searchBar1" class="searchBar">

                 <!-- SVG image--> 
                  <img id="searchBtn" src="css/SVGS/magnifying-glass.svg"> 

             </div>

        </main>
```

I have tried `<object>` tag too but it won't work. Here is the CSS part

```
    #searchBar1 {

    float:left;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 4% auto auto 26%;
    padding:0.99% 22% 0.4%  1%;

    border: solid thin rgba(74, 87, 98, 0.61);
    border:none;
    border-right:none;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);


}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #searchBar1 {
      margin: 4% auto auto 31%;
  }
}


#searchBtn {
    width: 3.45%;
    margin-bottom: 0.2%;
   float:left;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 4%;
    padding: 1% 1% 1.1% 1%;



    border-left:dashed thin rgba(74, 87, 98, 0.61);
     box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your padding and margins, removing them and writing the value for height and width should solve it.
Here is my code (I also corrected your comments in html comments are , and not <-- comment --!>)

```
<style>
#searchBar1 {
    width: 3.45%;
    height: 3.45%;
    float:left;


    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);


}



#searchBtn {
    height: 3.45%;
    width: 3.45%;
    float:left;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;

}
</style>
<main>
 <!-- Division with Search Bar as an input element and the svg as an image--> 
            <div class="searchDiv">
                <!-- A label --> 

                  <label class="searchBar" id="search">Taste of home right at your finger tips <br>   </label>
                 <!-- Search Bar --> 
                  <input type="text" id="searchBar1" class="searchBar">

                 <!-- SVG image--> 
                  <img id="searchBtn" src="css/SVGS/magnifying-glass.svg"> 

             </div>

        </main>
```

Iḿ happy seeing new members to the community

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work, I have already tried this. I was just trying trial and error through padding but  had no luck

Comment: This is strange. the code I sent to you resulted in both input and image with same sizes, at least for me. Have you tested my code? What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome along with Brackets. The height and width won't synchronize. The main problem I have, is with the height of the <img> element.

Comment: Nope it did not

Comment: This is strange, works perfectly to me. Sorry for not answering earlier/helped, I was helping another person and is already late night here... Good luck in your project ;)

Answer (score -1):

plz try this

Note in html comment is give by

like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

 
<main>
 <-- Division with Search Bar as an input element and the svg as an image--!> 
            <div class="searchDiv">
                <-- A label --!> 

                  <label class="searchBar" id="search">Taste of home right at your finger tips <br>   </label>
                 <-- Search Bar --!> 
                  <input type="text" id="searchBar1" class="searchBar">

                 <-- SVG image--!> 
                  <img id="searchBtn" src="css/SVGS/magnifying-glass.svg"> 

             </div>

        </main>
I have tried <object> tag too but it won't work. Here is the CSS part


@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #searchBar1 {
     /*argin: 4% auto auto 31%;*/
  }
}
#searchBtn:hover{
background-color:blue;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black;
}

#searchBtn {
position:fixed;
width:20px;
height:20px;
float:left;
border: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: white;
border:solid thin rgba(74, 87, 98, 0.61);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

}
.a{
border-radius:120px;}

</style>
<body>




       <div class="searchDiv">
              

                  <label class="searchBar" id="search">Taste of                     home right at your finger tips <br>   </label>
              
            
                  <input type="text" id="searchBar1" class="a"                         placeholder="  search" />

     
<img id="searchBtn" src=https://images.pexels.com/photos/313715/pexels-photo-313715.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=alcohol-bar-blur-313715.jpg&fm=jpg"> 

             </div>

</body>
</html>
```